# How to make requset in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sql, node.js, elasticsearch, curl

I have SQL query :

> select title, path from geo **where title in ["london","france"]  and path like "000000039%" and date not '2019-01-22' offset 0 limit 14 orderby title ask**;

How to make properly ElasticSearch query?

I made request like that, but doesn't work:

```
curl -XGET "http://service-monitoring--elastic:9200/geo/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "_source": [
    "title",
    "path"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"terms": {"title": ["london", "france"]}},
            {"wildcard": {"path": "000000039*"}}
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {"terms": {"date": "2019-01-22"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Error**

```
{"error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
        "line" : 8,
        "col" : 25
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
    "line" : 8,
    "col" : 25
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting results back and they're wrong, or not getting any results? any errors?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have documents that are supposed to answer to that query?

Comment: @gillyb yes sure, i has documents, added error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filtered` query was deprecated for a very long time and it was suggested to use `bool` instead. Now it's already removed since ES 5.0.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Try with:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "title",
    "path"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "title": [
                  "london",
                  "france"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "path": "000000039*"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "date": "2019-01-22"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```